# Generics cannot convert type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, sitecore

```
interface IComponent { /*code*/ }
interface IContent : IComponent { /*code*/ }
interface IMedia : IComponent { /*code*/ }
class A : IContent { /*code*/ }
class B : IMedia { /*code*/ }
class C : IContent, IMedia { /*code*/ }

private static T GetComponent<T>(string itemTemplate)
        where T : IComponent, new ()
{
    T component;
    switch (itemTemplate)
    {
        case "template_1":
            component = new A();
            break;
        case "template_2":
            component = new B();
            break;
        case "template_3":
            component = new C();
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("itemTemplate");
     }
     return component;
 }
```

I am getting these build errors where I'm creating instances of the derived types:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Objects.A' to 'T'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Objects.B' to 'T'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Objects.C' to 'T'
```

**EDIT**: The itemTemplate parameter is the name of the template of a Sitecore Item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why C# compiler prevents is there is the case that you can call:

```
GetComponent<A>("condition_2");
```

This call will not satisfy the compilers because "condition_2" will create new B, not A.

Since you only use Generic type T as the return type, I would suggest that you should not use Generic in here as simply following the factory pattern:

```
private static IComponent GetComponent(string condition)
{
    IComponent component;
    switch (condition)
    {
        case "condition_1":
            component = new A();
            break;
        case "condition_2":
            component = new B();
            break;
        case "condition_3":
            component = new C();
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("condition");
    }
    return component;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to cast to `T` - but first, somewhat annoyingly, you need to cast to `object` due to the rules around conversions to type parameters in C#.

I would personally get rid of the local variable though, which isn't helping you:

```
private static T GetComponent<T>(string condition)
        where T : IComponent, new ()
{
    switch (condition)
    {
        case "condition_1":
            return (T) (object) new A();
        case "condition_2":
            return (T) (object) new B();
        case "condition_3":
            return (T) (object) new C();
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("condition");
     }
}
```

You should really consider whether a generic method is appropriate here though... are you actually gaining anything over making the method return `IComponent` and letting the caller cast?

Basically, it's unclear what relation the condition has to the type being requested.

Comment: Or better yet, return IComponent

Comment: @SteveCzetty: Indeed - I hadn't actually checked that part of the question. Will edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated question to answer your question about the condition

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: Okay, but how do you intend to call this? Bear in mind that at the moment, you could only call it with the concrete types anyway, because of the `new()` constraint.